# Checking that ID exists in a jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a problem with this code. This is a product page, and if i click the save button, it saves the product ID into a jquery cookie. In the cookie, i store the ID-s like this example: 1,2,3,4....

If an ID is already in the cookie, i dont get that error, it always saves it again, than the ID will be duplicated in the cookie.

```
$('#favorite_button').click(function()
    {
         var cookie_message, item_id, most_van;
         item_id = <?php echo $kat_id  ?>;
         var cookie_val = $.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie");
         if(cookie_val){
             most_van = cookie_val.split(",");
         }
         else{
             most_van = [];
         }
         if($.inArray(item_id, most_van) === -1){
             most_van.push(item_id);
             $.removeCookie('kedvenc_termek_cookie');
             $.cookie('kedvenc_termek_cookie', most_van.join(","), { expires: 7, path: "/" });
             cookie_message = "ID saved okey.";
         }
         else {
             cookie_message = "This ID already in the cookie.";
         }
         $('#FavoritItemModalResult').html(cookie_message);$('#FavoritItemModal').modal('show');
         setTimeout(function()
         {
            $('#FavoritItemModal').modal('hide');
         }, 3000 );
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.inArray is like Array.prototype.indexOf, it strictly compares (===).

When you do most_van = cookie_val.split(",");, you get an array of strings.
Make sure you have the same types.

If `item_id` is an int, then you sould do:

```
most_van = cookie_val.split(",");
most_van = most_van.map(function(id) {
  return parseInt(id, 10)
})
```

Comment: What does this do?  (id, 10)

What sould i write here?

Comment: This transforms an array of strings, into an array of integers:
    most_van = most_van.map(function(id) {
      return parseInt(id, 10)
    })
`map` creates a new array, with items that the function passed returns, that function receives as parameter each item one by one.
`parseInt(id, 10)` transforms strings into integers, `10` to 10

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand this. What would be the full code i have to write?

Comment: I've added the modified code here: http://jsbin.com/sihoceh/edit?js . I cannot write it a comment.

Comment: return parseInt(id, 10); id = item_id? And why 10? What 10 mean?

Comment: It is the base (numeral system), it is good practice to add it. Decimal is 10, binary is 2.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132203/discussion-between-bogdanpetru-and-takacs-zoltan).